# Signal clipping in cascade transistor amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, bjt, gain, voltage-clipping, cascode

The two-layer voltage amplifier circuit can transfer a signal of up to Vi = 50 mV to the output without clipping.and 1st stages gain Av1=-6.41             .                               +15 volt is connected to the circuit from above, -15 volt dc source is connected from below. how can i calculate second stages gain ?

[image]

@G36

Comment: in amplifiers containing single transistors, the output value must be smaller than the dc voltage source, so that the output signal is not clipped, but I have no idea for cascade systems.

Comment: 2nd stage AC gain is approximately RC2/RE2.